# Using both gevent (or eventlet) and prefork workers with Celery

Tags: django, concurrency, celery, gevent, eventlet

Within the Concurrency section of the Celery docs it states that:

> ...mix of both Eventlet and prefork workers, and route tasks according to
>   compatibility or what works best

Source: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html#concurrency-eventlet

This means that it's possible to have a worker use the gevent/eventlet pool implementation while another uses a prefork pool.

The pool implementation can be specified when creating multiple workers with `celery multi`:

```
celery -A proj multi start 2 -P gevent -c 1000
```

This starts 2 gevent workers, but how can I can specify pool implementation on a per worker basis when using `celery multi`, so that one worker uses a gevent pool and the other uses prefork?

The `celery multi` docs don't mention anything regarding this specific matter, and the source code (`celery.bin.multi`) didn't really show that this was possible (unless I misread/misunderstood the code).

Comment: Maybe they meant that you could run two Celery instances with different worker configurations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So currently the only way to specify per worker Pool implementations is by running independent `celery worker` commands:

```
$ celery -A proj worker start -P gevent -Q:queue1 -c 500
$ celery -A proj worker start -P prefork -Q:queue2 -c 4
```

`celery multi` does not support `-P:worker1 gevent, -P:worker2 prefork`. This makes things difficult when using the init.d script provided within the Celery [docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html?highlight=celeryd_nodes#init-script-celeryd) to daemonize celeryd. So you either have to modify the init.d script or use something like Supervisor.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to start different implementations using `celery multi`. Just like [Amir R.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/394988/amir-r) said about `-Q` option.

```
celery multi start 2 -A default_prefork_queue -Q:2 gevent_queue_name -P:2 gevent -c:2 1000
```

By default it's `prefork` option selected.

In example above celery creates one worker with `gevent` pool with 1000 limit and one `prefork` worker with default limit of processes.

More examples [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.multi.html)

Comment: Can you point me pls where is -P mention in the doc

Comment: Yes, that's works in 2020, just checked with ps aux | grep celery

Comment: @comalex3 there is no `-P` mention in `multi` docs, only at https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-p
I just combined two approaches.